# Removing delete button from UITableView only if the row was swiped

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

When a row in my `UITableView` is swiped, the delete button is displayed. If I then add an item to this table, the row is inserted but the delete button wants to stay at the same index - so it moves to the row that it now in the same slot.

What I would like to happen is for the row to remove the delete button when I display my modal for adding a new item. In other words, I want to set editing to `NO`. However, it is not so simple - I *don't* want to exit edit mode when the user has entered it via the edit button. I would like to return the user to the same state that he left the table.

So - how do I tell a `UITableView` to remove the delete button, but not exit edit mode altogether? Even if the user has tapped 'edit', and then used the '-' icon to present a delete button, I would like to tell the table to remove the button but remain in edit mode if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that each `UITableViewCell` instance has its own [`editing` property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006938-CH3-SW17) (which you can further influence with some other properties, like `editingAccessoryType`). When you add a new row, you can leave the table view's `editing` property alone, but manually update the `editing` properties for both the old row that the user was editing and the new row that you just inserted.

Comment: But I would need a way to tell which cell has the delete button displayed. If I simply iterate through the visible cells checking isEditing, I will get a false positive for every cell when the user has put the whole table view into edit mode.

Comment: You may need to keep some extra internal state about which cell(s) is(are) in editing mode, updated when you receive the `-tableView:willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:` delegate call. It's not the best solution, I agree, but I can't really think of anything else.

Comment: I'm thinking of doing just that - but to know exactly which state (0, 1, 2, or 3) and not just isEditing, I think I will need to customize willTransitionToState: and store something. I'll give it a go